# React + Node get request with multiple parameters won't work

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, axios

I have a react + node app that connects to db. On frontend, react operates through axios, on backend, mongoose connects to MongoDB on Mlab.

I have different api calls that work just fine, but with the one with multiple parameters, I have an issue - api implementation function just not called.

The frontend call

```
axios.get(host_url + '/data/byuser', {params: {
        uid: this.state.uid,
        company: this.state.user_company,
        access_level: this.state.user_access
    }}
        .then(res => {
            if(res.status === 200) {
                // do stuff
        })
        .catch( error => {
            console.log(error.toString());
        })
```

The router snippet (current)

```
    app.route('/data/byuser')
    .get(getDataByManID);
```

Also tried

```
app.route('/data/byuser')
    .get( (req, res) => {
        getDataByManID(req, res);
    });
```

And

```
app.get('/data/byuser', getDataByManID);
```

The api implementation

```
module.exports.getDataByManID = (req, res) => {

    console.log('UID: ' + req.params.uid);
    console.log('Company: ' + req.params.company);
    console.log('Access level: ' + req.params.access_level);

    DataColl.find({
        $or: [
            {
                $and: [{
                    'uid': req.params.uid,
                    'company': req.params.company
                }]
            },
            {
                $and: [{
                    'company': req.params.company,
                    'access_level': {$lt: req.params.access_level}
                }]
            }
        ]
    }, function(err, dataItem) {
        if(err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else if(dataItem.length === 0) {
            res.send(404);
        } else {
            res.json(dataItem);
        }
    });
};
```

`console.log`s in `getDataByManID()` is just to know that this function is called, but the whole problem is that it doesn't.
It seems like paths are worked out. Postman gives proper response for all other requests with one get parameter or post requests, but 404 for this one, however, it shouldn't since there are entries in db that will be returned for this query. At least, `console.log`s should have been triggered.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the value of `host_url`?

Comment: Issue resolved by shortening route to `getdata`. I don't know how it affected anything, but it started working

Comment: host_url = 'localhost:3001' and works for other api calls